# How to generate Make File in Visual Studio 2008 Express Edition

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, makefile

Does anybody know how to generate Make File in Visual Studio C# 2008 Express Edition?

Answer (score 3):

Make files have little to no use in .NET world. Rather, consider using [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wea2sca5.aspx).

Comment: Do you have an example of generating makefile?

Comment: One more time: makefiles are nonexistent in .NET world.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. Download MonoDevelop 2.0
2. Open solution.
3. Right click on solution name -> Generate makefiles...

Answer (score 1):

Makefiles are really used for cross platform compiling or working with other build systems. When you are working with C# you are only really going to be compiling with Microsoft's tools or using Mono on another platform, so I don't think that you can. An alternative could be NAnt however depending on what you want to use your Makefile for.